# set a parent category in a product woocommerce

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I use this function to set a new category

```
wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $data[1], 'product_cat');
```

but I'd like to add a parent at this category... how could I do?

Comment: You wanna assign parent category to the category represented by `$data[1]` ? Or you wanna add the product represented by `$product_id` to `$data[1]` category and its parent category ?

Comment: i 'd like to add the product represented by $product_id to $data[1] category and its parent category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already got term object at `$data[1]` then you can simply access the parent by doing this-

```
$parent_id = $data[1]->parent;
```

If you got only term ID then you need to do-

```
$term = get_term($data[1], 'product_cat');
$parent_id = $term->parent;
```

After getting the parent term ID you can simply assign the product to the parent ID by doing-

```
wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $parent_id, 'product_cat', true);
```

***Update: Now your previous category data will not be replaced.***

Hope that helps.

Comment: if I execute this wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $parent_id, 'product_cat');  ....my previous category $data[1] is erased from $parent_id

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: @walle If the above solution helped you then please accept the answer by checking the check sign on the left of the answer. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your solution...it works but in my child category is the same with different father, so when I execute wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $parent_id, 'product_cat', true); or  wp_set_object_terms($product_id, array , 'product_cat', true); where array is the sequences of father category and child ... it checked the first child category with minor ID. There is a solution to associate child with father category?